# What is this question about planar graphs describing?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

To preface: I'm not looking for the answer to this question. I just need help understanding what the question is asking. I know a fair bit about planar graphs, but not a ton.

"Every vertex of a finite planar graph is the intersection two
squares, one triangle, and one hexagon. Either show why this
can’t happen, or find how many vertices, edges, and each type
of face are in the graph."

So in this question, what exactly does it mean by "the intersection of two squares, one triangle, and one hexagon."

I'm envisioning a planar graph that is 10 vertices, 13 edges, and 5 faces (which obeys Euler's formula). I started by drawing a hexagon, then on 2 of its outside edges, I drew squares that share one edge with the hexagon. Then I drew a single edge from the corner of one square to the other to make a triangle. Am I even close?

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't mind if your explanation includes the answer. I just wanted to state that I'm not looking specifically for the answer to the question. As I'm trying to answer a few questions of this type, knowing what it's talking about would be useful to me.

Comment: You might want to reread whatever your source is to get a handle on what the author means, but to me, it sounds like they're saying that each vertex appears in exactly one face with three sides, two faces with four sides, and one face with six sides.

Comment: Also, a hint: to see if this such a planar graph is possible, count the number of vertices, edges, and faces relative to the number of faces of each type, and use Euler's formula.